# How to pause and restart a css3 transition in jquery transit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-transit

I'm using jquery transit to move and element. I want to pause the animation and continue it  on click of a button. But i'm unable to figure out how to do it.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b4hwq/2/

I did try

```
stop().transition({});
```

but it is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were most of the way there with `.stop()` I just added a little logic to tell it what to do when it stops.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b4hwq/4/)**

```
$('button').click(function () {
    if (!$('.box').hasClass('stop')) { // if the box does not have class "stop"
        $('.box').stop().transition({  // stop the transition
            x: $('.box').offset().left + $('.box').width() / 2  // where the box should be when it stops
        }, 1).addClass('stop'); // simple add class for easy button control  
    } else { // if the box has class "stop"
        $('.box').transition({
            x: '350px' 
        }, 5000).removeClass('stop'); // continue with regularly scheduled programming then remove "stop"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`clearQueue()`**](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) to stop the animation

> clearQueue() : Stop the remaining functions in the queue

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/b4hwq/3/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"></div>
<button id="restartTransition">Click Me</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    opacity: 0.8;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 5%;
background: #505060;
border-radius: 1px;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
margin: -16px 0 0 -16px;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#restartTransition").on("click", function(){
        $('.box').clearQueue().transition({ x: '0px' },10);
        $('.box').transition({ x: '350px' },5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you donovan but I want to pause the animation and continue from the same place where I have paused. Above code will not pause it.

Comment: I think it's not possible with transit. There are no way to resolve this problem. Maybe use animate() to be able to execute stop().

Answer (score 1):

I have update the fiddle with the complete function from the transit library:

```
$('.box').transition({
            x: '350px',
            duration: 5000,
            complete: function() {
                alert("complete!");
            }
        });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4hwq/24/)

The complete function is still executed even when using clearQueue() or stop()